# What is the right way to read a zset in a redis cluster with an open-ended max bound with lettuce?

Tags: redis, lettuce

I have used `ZADD` command to insert a bunch of IDs with their corresponding scores into a redis instance. The score is basically a timestamp at which the `ZADD` is called.

Now I want to retrieve a list of IDs whose score is bigger than the timestamp of the moment five minutes ago.

The client is written in java and I am using lettuce as the redis client library.

I have a few questions:

1. Here is a link to the documentation of `zrangebyscore` on redis website (https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore). However on the lettuce website the counterpart is marked as 'Deprecated'. Is it a discrepancy of documentations, or lettuce has retired the support of this API?

[image]

2. I want to be able to retrieve a list of ID whose score is bigger than a certain number N, but I do not care about the upper-end.

In lettuce's documentation [this API `zrange`](https://lettuce.io/lettuce-4/release/api/com/lambdaworks/redis/api/async/RedisSortedSetAsyncCommands.html#zrange-K-long-long-) seems to be ideal for my purpose. However what sopt I can use to express that I do not care about the upper-bound? The documentation is not clear about this.

[image]

Comment: Upper bound can be bigger then scores available in the set. You can use Long.MAX_VALUE for upper end or current timestamp as your scores are based on timestamp. You can use **zrangebyscore** method which takes Range as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Redis zrange command is a zero index based command. This means the indexes start from 0 and increments as you add new elements. What's helpful here is you can retrieve the last index by specifying negative index -1, second from last by specifying -2 and so on. See more details about zrange on the redis website [here](https://redis.io/commands/zrange).

To retrieve the entire range, you can run

```
zrange keyname 0 -1
```

Note that '0' can be replaced by any index which means the above command would fetch a value starting at that index location. Therefore, this cannot be directly used to get all values higher than a specific score.

To retrieve from a specific score N, use

```
zrangebyscore keyname N +inf
```

[Here](https://lettuce.io/core/5.0.0.M2/api/io/lettuce/core/api/sync/RedisSortedSetCommands.html#zrangebyscore-K-io.lettuce.core.Range-io.lettuce.core.Limit-) is the right Lettuce API for zrangebyscore available since Lettuce 4.3